# Pact for PHP - 404 response code from mock server

Tags: php, api, testing, pact

I've tried to configure Pact for PHP using example configuration. My problem is I can run a `mockServer`, but every request I make returns `404` response. Of course I set everything up like in a GitHub readme. Still, I know server is visible (localhost config) but routes could not be registered.

Code example:

```
class PactTest extends \Tests\BaseTestCases\V2TestCase
{

/** @var MockServerConfig */
private $config;

public function setUp()
{
    // Create your basic configuration. The host and port will need to match
    // whatever your Http Service will be using to access the providers data.
    $this->config = new MockServerConfig();
    $this->config->setHost('localhost');
    $this->config->setPort(7200);
    $this->config->setConsumer('someConsumer');
    $this->config->setProvider('someProvider');
    $this->config->setHealthCheckTimeout(60);
    $this->config->setCors(true);

    // Instantiate the mock server object with the config. This can be any
    // instance of MockServerConfigInterface.
    $server = new MockServer($this->config);

    // Create the process.
    $server->start();

    // Stop the process.
    $server->stop();
}

public function testSimple()
{
    $matcher = new Matcher();

    // Create your expected request from the consumer.
    $request = new ConsumerRequest();
    $request
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->setPath('/test/abc')
        ->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // Create your expected response from the provider.
    $response = new ProviderResponse();
    $response
        ->setStatus(200)
        ->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
        ->setBody([
            'message' => $matcher->term('Hello, Bob', '(Hello, )[A-Za-z]')
        ]);

    // Create a configuration that reflects the server that was started. You can
    // create a custom MockServerConfigInterface if needed. This configuration
    // is the same that is used via the PactTestListener and uses environment variables.
    $builder = new InteractionBuilder($this->config);
    $builder
        ->given('a thing exists')
        ->uponReceiving('a get request to /test/abc')
        ->with($request)
        ->willRespondWith($response); // This has to be last. This is what makes an API request to the Mock Server to set the interaction.

    $service = new HttpClientService($this->config->getBaseUri()); // Pass in the URL to the Mock Server.
    $result  = $service->getTestAbc(); // Make the real API request against the Mock Server.

    $builder->verify();

    self::assertEquals('Hello, Bob', $result); // Make your assertions.
}
```

Where `getTestAbc()` is:

```
public function getTestAbc(): string
{
    $uri = $this->baseUri;
    $response = $this->httpClient->get("{$uri->getHost()}/test/abc", [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
    ]);
    $body   = $response->getBody();
    $object = \json_decode($body);

    return $object->message;
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Okay, changed my code. Now the server responds empty 200 for all kinds of requests did by Guzzle. No real mocks are registered. Everything is just HTTP/200.

Answer (score 1):

You're stopping the mock server in setUp. You should stop the server after the test in tearDown. I've noticed that's the code from the manual and it may be quite misleading, but I think it was intended as an example how to start/stop mock server by hand.